# How do I keep initial image size after apply transformation in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, registration

My question is, after applying an image transformation such as

```
    T =  [1,  0,  0;
          0,  1,  0;
         -5, -5,  1];
```

My initial image of 128x128 becomes 123x123. Is there a way I can keep the intial dimension of the image?

Here is how I am applying my transformation:

```
     Reg = imtransform(B, Tform,...
       'XData', [1 (size(B, 2)+Translation(3, 1))],...
       'YData', [1 (size(B, 1)+Translation(3, 2))],...
       'FillValues', 255);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the `size` property of `imtransform`. You can set the output image using this property. From the documentation: "A two-element vector of nonnegative integers. 'Size' specifies the number of rows and columns of the output image B."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @jucestain, by adding the

```
    +Translation(3,1) ...
```

portion, I was adding -5 to the initial dimension of 128!

I simply changed the code to

```
    Reg = imtransform(B, Tform,...
       'XData', [1 (size(B, 2))],...
       'YData', [1 (size(B, 1))],...
       'FillValues', 255);
```